# Accessing unique pointer variables and displaying them

Tags: c++

I'm fairly new to the site, and c++ programming. I've been trying to get something to work and I think I've hit a brick wall.

For my project I'm trying to make a Text based RPG. I'm trying to make it so a player can see their class's stats in battle, however I have no idea how to display it. Help would be appreciated.

```
include <iostream>
#include "mage.h"
#include "Warrior.h"
#include "Rogue.h"
#include "CharacterType.h"
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include "MainGame.h"
#include "Inventory.h"

using namespace std;


int GameStart()
{
    std::unique_ptr<blankCharacter> myCharacter;

    std::unique_ptr<Inventory> myInventory;


    string name;
    int choice;

    cout << " Please enter player name." << endl << endl;
    cin >> name;        
    system("cls");

    cout << "Please select fighting class." << endl << endl;
    cout <<" 1 - Mage" << endl;
    cout <<" 2 - Warrior" << endl;
    cout <<" 3 - Rogue" << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: //Mage
            myCharacter = std::unique_ptr<blankCharacter>(new Mage(70,100,150,60));
            myInventory = std::unique_ptr<Inventory>(new Inventory(10, 30));
        break;

        case 2: //Warrior
            myCharacter = std::unique_ptr<blankCharacter>(new Warrior(100,160,50,60));
            myInventory = std::unique_ptr<Inventory>(new Inventory(10, 30));
        break;

        case 3: //Rogue
            myCharacter = std::unique_ptr<blankCharacter>(new Rogue(90,160,70,100));
            myInventory = std::unique_ptr<Inventory>(new Inventory(10, 30));
        break;

        default: 
        cout << "Please select a relivant value 1 to 3" << endl << endl;
        break;
    }



    system("cls");


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just de-reference the pointer, `std::cout  << (*myCharacter) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `system("cls")` I will assume that you are using Windows. I would recommend that you read up on how the [`gotoxy`](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/gotoxy) function works.

Alternatively, if I'm wrong and you are using Linux, then use [the NCURSES library](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).

Both of these are console text manipulation options. If you want something more advanced for your game, I'm afraid that the answer won't be brief, but you can start by reading more about game engines like [unity](http://unity3d.com/) or going down to the very core of game graphics by learning [OpenGL](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) or [Direct X](http://www.directxtutorial.com/).

I apologize for not being more specific but the question was quite generic.

Comment: Thank you, i figured it out.

Comment: No problem, but may I ask you to either post the solution to your problem or mark my answer as the correct one so that others may benefit from this discussion? You can submit your own answer or edit the question itself to record how you've solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class blankCharacter
    {
     protected:
 int health;
 int stamina;
 int magic;
 int Attack1;
 int Attack2;
 int Attack3;
 int FirstAttack;
 int SecondAttack;
 int ThirdAttack;
 int healthTodeduct;




   public: 
blankCharacter(int Attack1,  int Attack2, int Attack3, int startingHealth, int        startingStamina, int startingMagic); // Constructor
~blankCharacter(); // Destructor
    }
```

The way the problem was solved was by pointing to the value.

```
     cout << "Magic: " << myCharacter->getMagic() << endl;
 cout << "Stamina: " << myCharacter->getStamina() <<     endl;
 cout << "Health: " << myCharacter->getHealth() << endl;
```